# Как сверстать кнопку со стрелкой внутри?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как более правильно сверстать вот такую кнопку?  http://prntscr.com/n3idtl
Первое что приходит на ум это сделать родительскому элементу border-radius:50% и background-image в виде самой стрелки. Может есть более элегантный способ?

Comment: Можно вставить в блок готовую монохромную иконку и залить фон. Просто и быстро. Или создать саму иконку с помощью svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью псевдоэлемента сделать:

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;;
  left: 9px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-left: 3px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Вы саму стрелку центрируете по вертикали и горизонтали с помощью top и left . Так вообще правильно делать? Или есть какие-то более надежные варианты?

Comment: @ДмитрийГаврилов, если у самой кнопки фиксированные размеры, то это оптимальный вариант

Answer (score 3):

Можно при помощи `html`+`css` и псевдо элемента `:after`:

```css
.arr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  border: 0.5em solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.arr:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1.05em;
  margin-left: 0.6em;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border-top: 0.5em solid;
  border-right: 0.5em solid;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="arr"></span>
```

Можно при помощи `svg`

```css
path, circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-15 -15 30 30" width="100" height="100">

  <circle r="10"></circle>
  <path d="M2,6 L-5,0 L2,-6"></path>

</svg>
```

PS: второй способ лично мне больше нравится